# Avoid layout page refresh on click of a link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am writing a web application in **MVC3** which consists of a master page (header / menus) which does not change. When I do something like click on a linkit causes refresh og whole page which is correct but this redraws the whole screen and becomes annoying because on every post back and the whole screen flickers.

Is there a way  not to refresh the layout page?

Thanks in advance for replies.

Comment: Google 'ajax'. MVC is a server side tech. You need to use client side scripting to avoid full page refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

Put all you want to refresh in one view and make a action point this,just like that:

```
//layout head...

<div id='maincontent'>
@Html.Action("Content","SomeControl")
</div>

//layout foot...
```

And use post to get the new content and replace it:

```
//in refresh event
$.post("/SomeControl/Content",function(data){
    $("#maincontent").html(data);
})
```